# How to get my pre Metaplex legacy token's update authority?

Tags: spl-token, metadata, spl, authority, upgrade-authority

I created a token before the existence of Metaplex, and during that time, token metadata was managed through the https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list repository. I now wish to update my token's metadata. However, I've noticed that there is an unknown address listed as the update authority, and it does not correspond to the address associated with the creation of my token. How can I proceed to update my token's metadata, and who might be the current update authority for my token?

Comment: Where are you seeing an update authority? If you were only using token-list, there wouldn't be a concept of an update authority or anything on-chain.